# NSData.writeToURL does not work at iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, simulator

I'm testing my app on iPhone 5s, in this app I'm saving audio file using `NSData.writeToURL(destinationUrl, atomically: true)`, but this line does not work.

How destinationUrl is beeing generated:

```
let documentsUrl =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!)

let fileName = remoteFileUrl.lastPathComponent

let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

While tested in iOS simulator - everythins was OK

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not write anything at runtime into the application bundle.
That will break the code signature of the application.

Comment: so where should I write data such way that it can be played by AVAudioPlayer in future?

Comment: The designated location the folder `Application Support`

Comment: didn't understand what you mean. how can I form the way to this folder like as in my question-post?

Comment: please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html section *Where You Should Put Your App’s Files*